# Is it possible to avoid caching .env files by Symfony Cache?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-cache

I'm using Symfony 4, and I would like to know if is possible to avoid that Symfony Cache component cache my `.env` files in **prod**
The main reason is that I'm trying to don't expose information saved there.

I'm thinking right now to prevent it by adding **+rwx** permission only to Apache's user and only +x for group and others users.

I'll appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not good apporach. ENV vars, can be exposed in many ways to user with access to server. Why are you not denying access to project folder for all users except Apache?

Comment: Yes. That's the correct approach. I can use Symfony Secrets system. Thanks @PavolVelky